# odbc dbConnect Can't open lib - file not found, but file is there?

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc, r-dbi

This worked perfectly for months. today I updated R and `DBI` library to `3.6.3` and now this..

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = Sys.getenv("DRIVER_PATH"), 
                 server = "aus_net", database = "ice", 
                  uid = Sys.getenv("USERNAME"), pwd = Sys.getenv("PASSWORD"))

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]
Can't open lib '/Applications/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.dylib' : file not found
```

yet

```
system("ls /Applications/IBM/informix/lib/cli/")
# [1] iclit09b.dylib
```

Any ideas?

#### What I know so far

- After tracing some of the code, I see `dbConnect()` calls an internal function from `odbc` (`odbc:::OdbcConnection`)
- i created a more detailed issue [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/356)

Comment: The error might originate from "odbc". https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/343
You can try reinstalling `install.packages("odbc")`

Comment: @DzimitryM I agree the issue definitely stems from `odbc` (or deeper, but not from `DBI` as I first assumed). From a scan of issue 343 it looks vaguely similar but unrelated (please let me know if I've missed some connection?)

Comment: The cited GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/356), which has now been closed, offers several ways to troubleshoot this situation.

Comment: @GordThompson I don't think it was ever solved. The [last comment](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/356#issuecomment-929797808) indicates it's unsolved and has more thumbs up than any other in the thread. I was the OP of that 3-year old thread and I never found a solution, I just moved on. [This](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/343#issuecomment-1162607028) comment in another thread indicates perhaps it was a bug in the driver. AFAICT I had everything as it ought to have been yet it didn't work (despite working fine in past), so I suspect it was a bug somewhere.